# How to render excel sheet using erb template used by wicked_pdf in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, erb, wicked-pdf

I am using wicked_pdf to render a PDF document; it works like a charm. The template (.erb file) used by wicked_pdf contains multiple HTML tables which are rendered perfectly on the PDF.

Now, I would like to just reuse the .erb template to render an excel spreadsheet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You need to actually attempt to solve the issue by yourself.

Comment: I just need some pointers as to which gem to use. I don't need the code. I couldn't find any gem which would use a .HTML.erb template to render an Excel .

Comment: Such questions are off-topic on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML table is simple enough, you can render the `html.erb` response with an Excel extension & content type, and it should open and work in Excel.

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: 'mypdf', template: 'show.html.erb'
    end
    format.xlsx do
      render template: 'show.html.erb',
        content_type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    end
  end
end
```

Otherwise, you'll likely need to author a specific template, using something Axlsx